# Check for any tangent siblings grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

Take for instance the CSS Grid below

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "Eight Four Nine"
    "Two Six Five"
    "One Seven Three";
}

.One { grid-area: One; }
.Two { grid-area: Two; }
.Three { grid-area: Three; }
.Four { grid-area: Four; background-color: yellow;}
.Five { grid-area: Five; }
.Six { grid-area: Six; }
.Seven { grid-area: Seven; }
.Eight { grid-area: Eight; }
.Nine { grid-area: Nine; }

.grid-container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="One">1</div>
  <div class="Two">2</div>
  <div class="Three">3</div>
  <div class="Four">4</div>
  <div class="Five">5</div>
  <div class="Six">6</div>
  <div class="Seven">7</div>
  <div class="Eight">8</div>
  <div class="Nine">9</div>
</div>
```

How can I with Javascript see that based on element 4 (yellow),

1. element 8 is to the left
2. nothing is above it
3. element 9 is to the right
4. element 6 is below

If the elements were in order, this would be significantly easier. You could get them simply by looking at the order of the DOM once you figured out the number of columns and rows. Can I still use a similar approach?

Comment: well, read the `grid-template-areas` using JS and you have your answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok, but that just gives me my grid area name, not the element which could be completely different in my case.

Comment: if you have the names, you have the matix structure and you can use it to identify the numbers. You know where each one belong.